# OAuth2 JWT Bearer token flow - "error": "invalid_client", "error_description": "invalid client credentials"

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps

i'm trying to get an access token, in order to make a REST call.
I've followed this guide https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&language=en_US

Right now, i've set the app's oauth *Permitted Users* policy to **Admin approved 
users are pre-authorized** and the *IP Relaxation* to **Relax IP restrictions**

In the profile for the user i am using, i've added the connected app *setup/manage users/profiles/myprofile/assigned connected apps*

(
for the record, initially i've also tried with *Permitted Users policy* set to **All users may self-authorize**, and i did the  authorization as it is mentioned here https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com

```
GET to https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=<redirect_url>&response_type=code
```

login with the salesforce credentials, click on Approve

```
POST to https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
```

with

- grant_type:authorization_code
- code: [*the value passed to the callback url*]
- client_id: [*client_id*]
- redirect_uri: [*the redirect_url sent in the GET and configured in the app settings*]
- client_secret:[*client_secret*]

)

In the OAuth config, i've added *all* the OAuth Scopes to **Selected OAuth Scopes** (to make sure this won't cause any errors)

So, with this setup, i make a

```
POST to https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
```

with

- grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
- assertion: [*the generated JWT assertion*]

Now we get to the interesting part:
on **sandboxes** everything **works**.

on **production** i get the following response back:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "invalid client credentials"
}
```

I am going mad trying to understand what's wrong here. I've noticed the following error in the *login history* (setup/manage users/login history)

```
Login Type:Remote Access 2.0 
Status: Failed: Missing Consumer Key Parameter 
Browser: Jakarta HTTP Common
```

If I decode the assertion, i get
Header:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256"
}
```

Payload:

```
{
  "iss": "[the client id]",
  "sub": "[my username]",
  "aud": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "exp": 1427455160
}
```

So, the things that are different from sandboxes (where it works) and production (where it is not working) :

- the url to which the POST is made https://test.salesforce.com -> https://login.salesforce.com  (tested also with https://[mydomain].my.salesforce.com)
- the audience (as the url changed)
- the username
- the application's client id (there are different apps on the sandbox and production, so they get different id's and client id's)

any ideeas ? :)

Comment: How long has been since you set the connected app ? It takes some time for the app to be available

Comment: ~ 2 weeks, i saw the message that the settings will take 2-10 minutes. I tried after 1h, same behavior

Answer (score 9):

The problem was the certificate uploaded in the Digital Certificate/Digital Signature field of the connected app. After uploading the proper certificate, the access token is returned.

Comment: was this certificate from self signed certificate in salesforce? or you created using a different platform?

Comment: What makes a "proper" certificate? I created a key and cert like this: `openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -sha256 -days 365`, and I'm getting the same error

Comment: As others have said, what makes a certificate "proper"?